# Computation Complexity polyL ⊆ QP, polyL ? P

Tags: computational-complexity

Following [Computation Complexity POLYLOGSPACE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042731/computation-complexity-polylogspace/4814330#4814330),

Given that polyL / POLYLOGSPACE is the complexity class

- $⋃^∞_{=1}(()^)$, k is integer.

QP / [Quasi-polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Quasi-polynomial_time) is the complexity class ,

- $⋃^∞_{c=1}TIME(2^{()^c})$, c is integer.

(a) How to prove that, polyL $⊆$ QP?

Reference: [wiki on polyL without proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PolyL)

(b) P is the Polynomial complexity class.

polyL ? P (any inclusion or equality between these two classes?)

i.e., if polyL ⊊ P, if P ⊊ polyL, or if neither is contained in the other?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a)

From the fourth inclusion rule, [Inclusion rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449934/can-somebody-explain-what-inclusions-of-complexity-classes-such-as-dtime-or)

$(())⊆(2^{(())})$

Here, plug in S(n) = (log n)^k, where k is an integer.

polyL ⊆ QP.

(b) polyL ≠ P, see [Note to part b](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042731/computation-complexity-polylogspace/4814330#4814330)  or [PolyL-wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PolyL).

But, it is unknown if polyL ⊊ P, if P ⊊ polyL, or if neither is contained in the other.